# Select an item that has id that contains &apos;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element whose id looks like

`link-21-&apos;some-text&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;sometext&apos;-1`.

I have no option to change the `id` at source. Is there a way to select them using the id?

`jQuery("#link-21-&apos;some-text&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;sometext&apos;-1")` is throwing an error for obvious reasons.  Are there any work around for this ?

Comment: who an earth will generate such ids and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it contains some special meaning character use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) or [escapes the special meaning character](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Check j[Query selctor docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  **!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~** ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").The W3C CSS specification contains [the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on [CSS character escape sequences for identifiers](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).

---

So it can be like following or escape each meta-character.

```
jQuery('[id="link-21-&apos;some-text&apos;&apos;&apos;&apos;sometext&apos;-1"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
  $('[id*="&apos"]')
```

select  elements which all have &apos in their ID

Comment: Assuming there's only one of them is a bit dangerous

Comment: I cannot be generic. Need to be pretty specific on this.

Comment: @SoorajChandran : you can include parent in the selection to be specific .  BTW how can you be specific if you dont have any idea if there can be many elements with such IDs

Answer (score 0):

Use you generic server side language to generate a simple id

use the proper jquery selector to select that element `$('#link-21')`

assuming you data in the db is properly formatted you should have a unique primary key, use that unique key to form your unique id

Comment: The OP clearly says: `I have no option to change the id at source.`

Comment: if he has access to the javascript files then its a strong possibility  may have access to the source code as well, this is more like a xy problem @DarrenSweeney